# Inconsistent 'The computed dimension of the solution does not equal N' error from dlqr synthesis

Tags: python, controller, python-control

I am encountering the error 'The computed dimension of the solution does not equal N' from the sg02ad function in slycot when using the Python Control Systems Library function dlqr for LQI controller synthesis, and this occurs inconsistently based on the values in the weighting matrices, particularly the Q matrix.

The error message makes me think there's a problem with the dimensions, but I don't understand how it can be a dimensional problem if I don't change the dimensions. For example, Q1 works fine but Q2 gives the mentioned error, all other inputs kept the same.

The pragmatic approach might be to just stick to the tuning values that work, but it's limiting my ability to tune the controller to just trial and error, so I'd prefer to understand why it's happening. Any ideas?

```py
Q1 = [[ 1.00e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.00e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
 [ 0.00e+00  8.21e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  8.21e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.31e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.31e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
 [ 1.00e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.01e+00 -7.00e-02 -2.38e-10  9.48e-03
   1.63e-07 -1.29e-03]
 [ 0.00e+00  8.21e-02  0.00e+00 -7.00e-02  3.73e+00  5.09e-11 -2.06e-03
  -3.28e-06  3.42e-02]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.31e+00 -2.38e-10  5.09e-11  4.96e+00 -4.62e-09
   2.28e-02  1.13e-09]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  9.48e-03 -2.06e-03 -4.62e-09  8.93e-02
   5.03e-06 -3.14e-02]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.63e-07 -3.28e-06  2.28e-02  5.03e-06
   5.25e-02 -5.48e-05]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00 -1.29e-03  3.42e-02  1.13e-09 -3.14e-02
  -5.48e-05  3.22e-01]]

Q2 = [[ 1.00e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.00e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
 [ 0.00e+00  3.28e+01  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  3.28e+01  0.00e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.31e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.31e+00  0.00e+00
   0.00e+00  0.00e+00]
 [ 1.00e-02  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.01e+00 -7.00e-02 -2.38e-10  9.48e-03
   1.63e-07 -1.29e-03]
 [ 0.00e+00  3.28e+01  0.00e+00 -7.00e-02  3.65e+01  5.09e-11 -2.06e-03
  -3.28e-06  3.42e-02]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.31e+00 -2.38e-10  5.09e-11  4.96e+00 -4.62e-09
   2.28e-02  1.13e-09]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  9.48e-03 -2.06e-03 -4.62e-09  8.93e-02
   5.03e-06 -3.14e-02]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00  1.63e-07 -3.28e-06  2.28e-02  5.03e-06
   5.25e-02 -5.48e-05]
 [ 0.00e+00  0.00e+00  0.00e+00 -1.29e-03  3.42e-02  1.13e-09 -3.14e-02
  -5.48e-05  3.22e-01]]
```

I've tried some different values for the elements of the Q matrix and would expect all of them to at least produce a gain matrix of the correct dimensions as long as the tuning values are valid numbers.